# Navigate to different page on successful login

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import './app.css';

import Login from './auth/pages/login';
import DashBoard from './dashboard/dashboard';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/auth/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard} />
          <Redirect from="/" exact to="/auth/login" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

login.tsx

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const authHandler = async (email, password) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  try {
    const authService = new AuthService();

    await authService
      .login({
        email,
        password
      })
      .then(() => {
        history.push('/dashboard');
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

From the above code I'm trying to navigate to dashboard on successful login.
The auth handler function is being called once the submit button is clicked.
The login details are successfully got in authhandler function, but once I use history to navigate I get the following error

```
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error text is pretty clear. You can not call `useHistory`, or any other hook, outside of functional component. Also, hooks must be called unconditionally, on top of component. Try to call `useHistory` inside your actual component and pass `history` as a parameter to `authHandler`.

Comment: I don't think passing `history` to `authHandler` is a good idea, the best would make `authHandler` only for calling the async request and call `history` in `.then`. This will make `authHandler` only handle the `auth` part.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `authHandler` is an async function and using a hook inside a "normal" function don't work. It breaks the [rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

What you need to do is separate `authHandler` and `history.push('/dashboard')`.

What you can do is return the async request and use `.then` to call `history.push`.

```
const authHandler = async (email, password) => {
    const authService = new AuthService();
    // returning the request
    return await authService
      .login({
        email,
        password
      })
};
```

And inside your component you use the `useHistory` hook and call `authHandler` on some action.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const history = useHistory()

    const onClick = (email, password) => {
        authHandler(email, password) 
            .then(() => history.push('/dashboard'))
    }
    return (...)
}
```